# Размещение элементов на странице по кругу

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Не получается разместить карточки по кругу:

```css
.cards_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  right: 15%;
}

.card {
  width: 61px;
  height: 52px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card_title,
.card_rating {
  margin: 0;
}

.card:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateX(50deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="cards">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cards_wrapper">

      <div class="card">
        <img class="card_img" src="images/profile2.1.png" alt="">
        <h4 class="card_title">Иванов Сергей</h4>
        <p class="card_rating">4.9</p>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <img class="card_img" src="images/profile2.1.png" alt="">
        <h4 class="card_title">Иванов Сергей</h4>
        <p class="card_rating">4.9</p>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <img class="card_img" src="images/profile2.1.png" alt="">
        <h4 class="card_title">Иванов Сергей</h4>
        <p class="card_rating">4.9</p>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <img class="card_img" src="images/profile2.1.png" alt="">
        <h4 class="card_title">Иванов Сергей</h4>
        <p class="card_rating">4.9</p>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <img class="card_img" src="images/profile2.1.png" alt="">
        <h4 class="card_title">Иванов Сергей</h4>
        <p class="card_rating">4.9</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Как сделать вот такое размещение?

[image: 1]

[codepen](https://codepen.io/WebArtSpb/pen/RwoYbmv)

Comment: Когда что-то делаешь, тогда не получается. А пока мы не видим даже попыток сделать что-то. Отредактируйте вопрос - приложите разметку и стили.

Comment: К коллегам здесь всегда обращаюсь в последнюю очередь. Сначала мониторю доступные ресурсы. Получается не всегда ввиду малого опыта пока еще неумения находить нужную информацию потому что не всегда нахожу правильные ключевые слова! Надеюсь на Ваше терпение и понимание!

Comment: Начальная разметка, примерные размеры, доступные картинки сильно поспособствуют терпению и особенно пониманию ;-)

Comment: А, ок. ) Благодарю!) Буду иметь ввиду..) Сейчас поправлю..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Лучше было бы, если задействовать SVG и JS, но т.к. в метках вопроса указаны только HTML и CSS, то вот Вам приближенный вариант:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.cards_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 485px; width: 485px;
  font: bold 11px/1em "Arial", sans-serif;
  background-image: radial-gradient( circle at center, #fff0 53px, #fff 54px, #fff 57px, #abd2ee 58px, #abd2ee 60px, #fff 61px, #fff 106px, #d5e1ec 107px, #d5e1ec 143px, #fff0 144px, #fff0 169px, #d5e1ec 170px, #d5e1ec 172px, #fff0 173px), url(https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image);
  background-position: 0 0, center;
  background-size: auto, 110px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.cards_wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: calc(100% - 66px);
  height: calc(100% - 66px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px dashed #d5e1ec;
}

.cards_wrapper::after {
  content: "★ 4.9";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, -66px);
  padding: 6px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #4facf1;
  color: #fff;
}

.angle_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}
.angle_wrapper:nth-child(2) { transform: rotate(60deg); }
.angle_wrapper:nth-child(3) { transform: rotate(120deg); }
.angle_wrapper:nth-child(4) { transform: rotate(180deg); }
.angle_wrapper:nth-child(5) { transform: rotate(240deg); }
.angle_wrapper:nth-child(6) { transform: rotate(300deg); }

.card {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px; width: 100px;
  transform-origin: 50% 33px;
}
.angle_wrapper:nth-child(2) .card { transform: rotate(-60deg); }
.angle_wrapper:nth-child(3) .card { transform: rotate(-120deg); }
.angle_wrapper:nth-child(4) .card { transform: rotate(-180deg); }
.angle_wrapper:nth-child(5) .card { transform: rotate(-240deg); }
.angle_wrapper:nth-child(6) .card { transform: rotate(-300deg); }

.card_img {
  width: 66px; height: 66px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #d5e1ec;
}

.card_title, .card_rating {
  margin: 0;
  color: #696d78;
}

.card_rating {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #abd2ee;
}
```

```html
<section class="cards">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cards_wrapper">

      <div class="angle_wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card_img" src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="">
          <h4 class="card_title">Иванов Сергей</h4>
          <p class="card_rating">★ 4.9</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="angle_wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card_img" src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="">
          <h4 class="card_title">Иванов Сергей</h4>
          <p class="card_rating">★ 4.9</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="angle_wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card_img" src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="">
          <h4 class="card_title">Рождественский Сергей</h4>
          <p class="card_rating">★ 4.9</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="angle_wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card_img" src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="">
          <h4 class="card_title">Иванов Сергей</h4>
          <p class="card_rating">★ 4.9</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="angle_wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card_img" src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="">
          <h4 class="card_title">Ким Ли</h4>
          <p class="card_rating">★ 4.9</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="angle_wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card_img" src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="">
          <h4 class="card_title">Иванов Сергей</h4>
          <p class="card_rating">★ 4.9</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Замечательно Юра получилось

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: ну, так выцыганил разметку и скриншот, чего бы не сделать :) Я сейчас вот [тут](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#ua-stylesheet) залип - если воплотят эту фичу со счётчиками, то мой код сократится вдвое, а соседний ответ может потерять актуальнось :) Ведь как было бы удобно использовать значения counters() совместно с calc(). Эх...

Comment: Очень здорово! Спасибо Вам огромное! ) Буду разбираться!)

Comment: А почему JS проще?

Comment: @АртемН: JS не проще, но короче, за счёт динамической генерации элементов и сложных вычислений, которые в CSS недоступны.

Answer (score 5):

Один из вариантов верстки: Взять `position: relative` блок размером `0x0 px`, расположив его по центру, вставить в него необходимое количество картинок `position: absolute`, указывая им соответствующие координаты в `top: px; left: px;`

Но было бы приятно не считать их руками, а чтобы JS сам всё посчитал и вставил для любого количества картинок)

Для справки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.к. в браузере ось `y` перевернута (`y` растет в направлении «вниз»), нужно будет брать отрицательные значения: `- R * sin(a)`. Изменение знака `x` будет влиять на расположение «по» часовой стрелке или «против».

Реализация (сохранена исходная разметка карточек из вопроса, текст не выровнен):

```js
(function() {      
  let data = [
    { name: 'a', rate: 1, src: 'https://imgur.com/PXsAs3a.png' },
    { name: 'b', rate: 2, src: 'https://imgur.com/PXsAs3a.png' },
    { name: 'c', rate: 3, src: 'https://imgur.com/PXsAs3a.png' },
    { name: 'd', rate: 4, src: 'https://imgur.com/PXsAs3a.png' },
    { name: 'e', rate: 5, src: 'https://imgur.com/PXsAs3a.png' },
  ];
  
  /***/
  const R = 80;
  const IMG_SIZE = 40;
  
  /***/
  let parent = document.querySelector(".js-center");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let radian = i * (2 * Math.PI / data.length) - 0.5 * Math.PI;
    
    let x = R * Math.cos(radian) - IMG_SIZE / 2;
    let y = R * Math.sin(radian) - IMG_SIZE / 2;
    
    let params = Object.assign({x, y}, data[i]); // (*1)
    
    create_card(params);
  }
  
  /***/
  function create_card(obj) {
    let root = document.createElement("div");
    let img_style = `style="width: ${IMG_SIZE}px; height: ${IMG_SIZE}px;"`;
    
    root.innerHTML = (`
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card_img" src="${obj.src}" ${img_style}>
        <h4 class="card_title">${obj.name}</h4>
        <p class="card_rating">${obj.rate}</p>
      </div>
    `);
    
    let card = root.firstElementChild;
    
    card.style.left = obj.x + "px";
    card.style.top  = obj.y + "px";
    
    parent.appendChild(card);
  }

})();
```

```css
.js-center {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 80px;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
}

.card_img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 40px;
  border: 5px solid #f50;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="js-center"></div>
</div>
```

**(*1)** `let params = Object.assign({x, y}, data[i]);`

`{ x: x, y: y }` создание такого объекта можно сократить до `{x, y}`, в случае, если название ключа совпадает с названием переменной, использованной как значение. `Object.assign` добавляет все свойства из объекта `data[i]` в первый объект. Получается объект с ключами `{ x, y, name, rate, src }`, который передается как параметр функции.

Comment: Мне кажется нужна доработка скрипта  при изменении констант размера изображения и радиуса const R = 300;
  const IMG_SIZE = 100; верстка  распадается и уходит влево https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOOJz.png:

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Расположение центральной точки регулируется в CSS, здесь это `.js-center { margin: 80px }` — оно, задано жестко пикселями. Будет время - да, надо бы сделать резиновую версию) Хотя, вариант @UModeL больше похож на правду. Затупил, забыл про встроенные CSS-rotate)